# return a vector vs use a parameter for the vector to return it

Tags: c++, vector, return

With the code below, the question is:

If you use the "returnIntVector()" function, is the vector copied from the local to the "outer" (global) scope? In other words is it a **more time and memory consuming** variation compared to the "getIntVector()"-function? (However providing the same functionality.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<int> returnIntVector()
{
   vector<int> vecInts(10);
   for(unsigned int ui = 0; ui < vecInts.size(); ui++)
      vecInts[ui] = ui;

   return vecInts;
}

void getIntVector(vector<int> &vecInts)
{
   for(unsigned int ui = 0; ui < vecInts.size(); ui++)
      vecInts[ui] = ui;
}

int main()
{
   vector<int> vecInts = returnIntVector();
   for(unsigned int ui = 0; ui < vecInts.size(); ui++)
      cout << vecInts[ui] << endl;
   cout << endl;

   vector<int> vecInts2(10);
   getIntVector(vecInts2);
   for(unsigned int ui = 0; ui < vecInts2.size(); ui++)
      cout << vecInts2[ui] << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In theory, yes it's copied.  In reality, no, most modern compilers take advantage of [return value optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization).

So you can write code that acts semantically correct.  If you want a function that modifies or inspects a value, you take it in by reference.  Your code does not do that, it creates a new value not dependent upon anything else, so return by value.

Comment: +1 Interesting article on the subject here: http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/

Answer (score 10):

Use the first form: the one which returns vector. And a good compiler will most likely optimize it. The optimization is popularly known as [Return value optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization), or RVO in short.

Answer (score 4):

Others have already pointed out that with a decent (not great, merely decent) compiler, the two will normally end up producing identical code, so the two give equivalent performance.

I think it's worth mentioning one or two other points though. First, returning the object does officially copy the object; even if the compiler optimizes the code so that copy never takes place, it still won't (or at least shouldn't) work if the copy ctor for that class isn't accessible. `std::vector` certainly supports copying, *but* it's entirely possible to create a class that you'd be able to modify like in `getIntVector`, but not return like in `returnIntVector`.

Second, and substantially more importantly, I'd generally advise against using *either* of these. Instead of passing or returning a (reference to) a vector, you should normally work with an iterator (or two). In this case, you have a couple of perfectly reasonable choices -- you could use either a special iterator, or create a small algorithm. The iterator version would look something like this:

```
#ifndef GEN_SEQ_INCLUDED_
#define GEN_SEQ_INCLUDED_

#include <iterator>

template <class T>
class sequence : public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, T>
{ 
    T val;
public:
    sequence(T init) : val(init) {}
    T operator *() { return val; }
    sequence &operator++() { ++val; return *this; }
    bool operator!=(sequence const &other) { return val != other.val; }
};

template <class T>
sequence<T> gen_seq(T const &val) {
    return sequence<T>(val);
}

#endif
```

You'd use this something like this:

```
#include "gen_seq"

std::vector<int> vecInts(gen_seq(0), gen_seq(10));
```

Although it's open to argument that this (sort of) abuses the concept of iterators a bit, I still find it preferable on practical grounds -- it lets you create an initialized vector instead of creating an empty vector and then filling it later.

The algorithm alternative would look something like this:

```
template <class T, class OutIt>
class fill_seq_n(OutIt result, T num, T start = 0) {
    for (T i = start; i != num-start; ++i) {
        *result = i;
        ++result;
    }
}
```

...and you'd use it something like this:

```
std::vector<int> vecInts;
fill_seq_n(std::back_inserter(vecInts), 10);
```

You can also use a function object with `std::generate_n`, but at least IMO, this generally ends up more trouble than it's worth.

As long as we're talking about things like that, I'd also replace this:

```
for(unsigned int ui = 0; ui < vecInts2.size(); ui++)
    cout << vecInts2[ui] << endl;
```

...with something like this:

```
std::copy(vecInts2.begin(), vecInts2.end(), 
          std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

Answer (score 0):

In theory, the `returnIntVector` function returns the vector by value, so a copy will be made and it will be more time-consuming than the function which just populates an existing vector.  More memory will also be used to store the copy, but only temporarily; since `vecInts` is locally scoped it will be stack-allocated and will be freed as soon as the `returnIntVector` returns.  However, as others have pointed out, a modern compiler will optimize away these inefficiencies.

Answer (score 0):

In C++03 days, getIntVector() is recommended for most cases. In case of returnIntVector(), it might create some unncessary temporaries.

But by using [return value optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) and [swaptimization](http://pizer.wordpress.com/2009/06/25/c-exploiting-copy-elisions/), most of them can be avoided. In era of C++11, the latter can be meaningful due to the move semantics.

Answer (score -1):

**returnIntVector** is more time consuming because it returns a copy of the vector, unless the vector implementation is realized with a single pointer in which case the performance is the same.

in general you should not rely on the implementation and use **getIntVector** instead.

Comment: and also I don't think you should rely on compiler optimizations unless you are writing for a specific compiler. and for what reason would you do it?

Comment: You aren't relying on implementation details here for correctness, just for speed. It's perfectly reasonable to rely on compiler optimizations for speed - what else are they for?

Comment: You're relying on a compiler *not* optimizing, when in fact most do.  Consider you have another function that takes a vector by value because it needs a copy. You can pass the result of returnIntVector to it, and on most compilers you've made *ZERO* copies.  But if you use getIntVector, since you are working with an l-value, you *must* make a copy.  Now, your version of the code is *less* efficient than the semantically correct version.

Comment: I think one shouldn't write code thinking that this or that compiler will eventually optimize. one should rely only on what the language specification says. the same code may be compiled on different compilers and the same one can change overtime. the programmer doesn't have to care about its underlying complexity. to me it's like drawing a line that allows developers to freely work on their side without knowledge of what the other does. in this case one is the coder and the other is the compiler's designer.

Comment: @qwlice: But returnIntVector *doesn't* rely on compiler optimizations, it merely takes advantage of them if they are there.  Surely you've heard this piece of wisdom [-- ... premature optimization is the root of all evil ... -- Donald Knuth](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).  When you write a function like getIntVector, you are sacrificing code correctness and clarity because you are worried about the copy that might be made when you return by value.  This is premature optimization.

Comment: Why create these copies in the first? Just pass/return a pointer. No need to worry about compiler or implementation details then or everafter.

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley : I get your point but you forgot that the question was about **what is more time and memory consuming**. the answer is that one function makes a copy that is in general more time consuming. compiler optimizations are an extra that has nothing to do with the language specification. talking about premature optimization here is really out of place

Comment: @qwlice: If the question was about copying vs modifying a vector in place, you'd be right.  But that's not the question.  The question is about returning by value.  And we're talking about reality here, not some fantasy land where compilers are stupid.  In reality, returning by value does not cause a copy to be made.  In reality, every modern compiler takes advantage of return value optimization.  And compilers are only getting smarter.